# Два ярлыка, одно приложение

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Манифест:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Launcher"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon2"
        android:label="Launcher" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".formats.HD_Choice" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".formats.Wide_Choice" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

В приложении собираюсь сделать две иконки, одна "Настройки"( в манифесте это MainActivity) и Лаунчер(Launcher).
Проблема в том, что при выходе одной из иконок, через HOME-кнопку, переходя во вторую, открывается первая в том же состоянии.

Если убрать эту комбинацию "action.Main"+"category.Launcher", то не создается иконка.

Comment: В этом видео показывается приложение, в которой этот механизм реализован так, как я спрашиваю, спасибо https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVuKlVKZgQc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Я нашел ответ.
В AndroidManifest.xml для нужных активити добавьте следующее в intent-filter:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

А также установите lable(имя ярлыка) и icon(иконку)

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_Launcher"
```

**Пример,**

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.Launcher"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/labelLauncher"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Удалите `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` у последних двух `activity`.

Comment: Нет, не работает